# Can we make a clickable link to another page in draw.io?

Tags: draw.io

Can we make a clickable link to another page in draw.io ?

For example, I would like to click on rectangle element in Page 1 and the click forward me to the page 2 in draw.io ?
- like a box in the box ?

Thank you

Comment: could you please accept one of the correct answers?

Answer (score 20):

I dont know why this question hasn't been answered yet.

It's pretty simple:

- Right click the item you want to add a link to and select "Edit Link"
- On the Edit Link modal, you can add an external URL, or link to another page from the same project* (which, I belive, was your case a year ago when you asked).
- Done.

To test your page, go to the "File" menu (top left), and select "Publish -> Link..." and then click "Create".

*Other pages from the same project will only appear on the list if you have created them on a different tab (tabs are at the bottom of the editor).

Answer (score 4):

**Since 2020-11-11:**

draw.io / diagrams.net natively supports linking from any shape to other tabs:

- Right click any shape or text
- Select "Edit Link"
- Select the tab you want to link to in the second radio button dropdown
- Click "Apply"

**The link will work in the view mode:**

- Select Menu > File > Publish > Link
- Optional: Untick "Edit" to prevent editing for viewers
- Click "Create"
- Copy the generated link to share with others

Links in the viewer will be clickable